# Receiving "No Such Table" error while trying to access existing MySQL database using Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

**myapp.py**

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

app.config['SQLAlchemy_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:root@localhost/linkmanager'

class Link(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'link'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text)
    url = db.Column(db.Text)
    type = db.Column(db.Integer)
    insert_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

@app.route('/links', methods=['GET'])
def links():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        results = Link.query.limit(10).offset(0).all()

        json_results = []
        for result in results:
            d = {
                    'id': results.id,
                    'title': results.title,
                    'url': results.url,
                    'type': results.type,
                    'insert_date': results.insert_date
                }
            json_results.append(d)
        return jsonify(items=json_results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Error message when I try to access localhost:5000/links:

**sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: link u'SELECT link.id AS link_id, link.title AS link_title, link.url AS link_url, link.type AS link_type, link.insert_date AS link_insert_date \nFROM link\n LIMIT ? OFFSET ?' (10, 0)**

I know that the table does exist because I set it up with phpAdmin and have accessed it from the command line. I also tried connecting to it with Java and was successful... I have no idea why this is not working! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setting name is wrong. Change

```
app.config['SQLAlchemy_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:root@localhost/linkmanager'
```

to

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:root@localhost/linkmanager'
```